# Is it possible to not log in the user after password reset flow azure ad b2c?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I was wondering if it's possible to not log in the user after the password reset flow?

So basically what I want is to let user reset their password, but after the process the user to be redirected to login flow.

Comment: Are you using a user flow or a custom policy?

Comment: A standard user flow

Comment: Are you referencing this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#prerequisites)? Have you tried graph api?

Comment: Try to reset the user password using graph api. After that, you will not be asked to log in as a user.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#reset-a-users-password--